# Malloc, Realloc, Free

Tags: c, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

```
int *p=malloc(20);
```

Now Heap will allocate memory of 20 bytes. And returns the address of 1st byte to pointer p.(Assuming no NULL pointer is returned).

Now I do this,

```
int *q=realloc(p, 40);
```

Now their are following possibilities:

1]. q=p

2]. q!=p

3]. q=NULL

Forgot about Possibility 2 and 3.

Now I write:

```
free(p);
```

Now What will happen?

Will First 20 bytes will become free and rest will still remain allocated or all the 40 bytes will get free or something else?

Comment: If `realloc` returns a non-null pointer, the pointer passed in is invalidated (i.e. `free`d), you don't need to do that yourself.

Comment: It will free the 40 bytes. It just happens that it did not need to move anything in the reallocation

Comment: If `q == p` it makes no difference which you pass to `free`, which has no idea what variable you used, only its value. But it would be bad practice, I take it to be an academic question.

Comment: It's not your question, but there's no way in standard C to test if `p==q` after the call to realloc. If the realloc call moved the memory then `p` is not a valid pointer, and `p==q` may be undefined behavior (since `p` and `q` do not point to parts of the same object).

Comment: @PaulHankin That is correct regardless of what happened to the memory and where the new pointer points to. The value of p is simply indeterminate.

Comment: @2501 yes, I've read your answer and agree with it.

Comment: Your supposition is that `p == q` and then you ask what the consequences of that supposition are. But by making that supposition you are saying "I state that my compiler produces code that has a particular behaviour when in an undefined behaviour situation".  Since you are making that supposition, then **you** are the only person who can tell us what `free` does; you've already said that you are supposing that undefined behaviour has a particular behaviour; *you have to keep on doing that*.

Comment: @EdHeal `free(p)` is undefined behaviour; not "it will free the 40 bytes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The call to free will cause undefined behavior. Here is the reasoning:

The function realloc will deallocate<sup>1</sup> the space pointer to by pointer p.

The lifetime<sup>2</sup> of an object, p pointed to, ends at the deallocation.

The function free receives a pointer to deallocated space and causes undefined behavior<sup>3</sup>.

Additionally, the value of the pointer p after the realloc call is indeterminate and its usage may cause undefined behavior due to trap representations.

In other words, even if the pointer returned from realloc points to the start of the same space as pointer p did, the object allocated by realloc counts as a new object with new lifetime, and may not be deallocated using the pointer p.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.22.3.5 The realloc function 2)
The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a
pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size.

<sup>2</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.22.3 Memory management functions 1)
The lifetime of an allocated object extends from the allocation
until the deallocation

<sup>3</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 7.22.3.3 The free function 2)
Otherwise, if
the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, the
behavior is undefined.

<sup>4</sup> (Quoted from: ISO/IEC 9899:201x 6.2.4 Storage duration of objects 2)
The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when
the object it points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

From malloc / realloc man page

> The realloc() function tries to change the size of the allocation
>   pointed to by ptr to size, and returns ptr.  If there is not enough
>   room to enlarge the
>        memory allocation pointed to by ptr, realloc() creates a new allocation, copies as much of the old data pointed to by ptr as will
>   fit to the new allocation,
>        frees the old allocation, and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.

You should take a look about how `malloc()`, `free()` and `realloc()` works.
The easiest way is with a simple implementation.

http://arjunsreedharan.org/post/148675821737/write-a-simple-memory-allocator

Comment: The linux man pages typically describe the behaviour of how the functions are implemented on linux systems, which may differ from the Standard C specification and behaviour on other platforms.

Answer (score -2):

realloc(p,new_size) resize the memory block pointed to by p that was previously allocated with a call to malloc or calloc.
now if memory is available adjacent to the previously allocated memory the it returns same pointer that we pass to it as here p
so in this case if you will free(q) the space to which both p & q are pointing will be deleted.

but if memory is not  available adjacent to the previously allocated memory then it returns different pointer for newly allocated space so in this case if you will free(q) newly allocated space will be deleted

in both cases memory deleted is 40 bits